# node.js fluent-ffmepg with createWriteStream fails

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am trying to use `fluent-ffmpeg` node package with `createReadStream` and `createWriteStream`.

However, if I replace this line:

```
  .output(fs.createWriteStream('assets/transcode-video.mp4'), {end: true})
```

I write this

```
  .output('assets/transcode-video.mp4', {end: true})
```

it works. But I literally followed the [documentation](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#specifying-inputs). I appreciate any help or hint.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
const logger = console;

const options = {
  timeout: 60, // seconds
  logger
};

ffmpeg(fs.createReadStream('assets/video.webm'), options)
  .output(fs.createWriteStream('assets/transcode-video.mp4'), {end: true})
  .on('end', () => console.log('Finished processing'))
  .run();
```

Error:

> ```
> > node src/index.js
>
> events.js:292
>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>       ^
>
> Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: pipe:1: Invalid argument
> ```

[My repository for complete code](https://github.com/amir734jj/node-ffmepg-playground/tree/13103506ffbda636ce2eeaa8962c4bd682d84ead)

Comment: I had a similiar issue, this was because the output was not defined right. I cant remember what it was detail, had something to do with mp4/http streaming. Preset "flashvideo" worked then for me: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/blob/master/lib/presets/flashvideo.js

Answer (score 0):

In the `.output(fs.createWriteStream('assets/transcode-video.mp4'), {end: true})` remove `fs.write()`, as it is unnecessary, ffmpeg will create the output file without the need you do it manually.

Your code will look like this:

```
const fs = require ('fs');
const ffmpeg = require ("fluent-ffmpeg");
const logger = console;

const options = {
  timeout: 60, // seconds
  logger
};

ffmpeg (fs.createReadStream ('out.mp3'), options)
  .output ('transcode-video.mp4', {end: true})
  .on ('start', (a) => console.log (a))
  .on ('end', () => console.log ('Processing completed'))
  .run();
```

Comment: I know removing that will work but I wanted to use `createWriteStream` instead

Comment: It does not work with `createWriteStream`, as fluent-ffmpeg is "converting" everything to ffmpeg syntax. This syntax requires that the output be a string.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work with `createWriteStream`, as fluent-ffmpeg is "converting" everything to ffmpeg syntax. This syntax requires that the output be a string